# Unable to commit git repo

Tags: pre-commit-hook, git-for-windows

I am trying to commit my code from a Windows system into a git repository. But whenever I execute "git commit" command, I get the below error:

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 11: py: command not found
```

Also tried adding the python path to the "Path" system vriables. But no resolution.

Comment: Disable (e.g., rename) the hook. Or ask the one who wrote it what's up with it.

Answer (score 4):

`Py` is the Windows `Python` launcher. It helps locating the correct `Python` version, in the case the system has installed multiple versions. You can find more information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher).

Assure that you have checked the "Install py" option when installing python on your system.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This really helped. I re-installed Python by checking the "py launcher". And it worked fine.

Comment: Awesome! Happy I could help.

Comment: I confirm that it also works by just ticking "py launcher", all other options can be unchecked (if you don't need them for something else).